# db2-AIX multiple admin accounts

Tags: db2

I'd need to give (aside the instance owner and the administration server) the user rights as database administrator to a group of people already created on the AIX server. Is it possible? what will happen in case of someone will modify something to the db2 config for example?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you only need them to be an administrator of the database, you can grant them DBADM authority.

```
grant DBADM on database to (user or group) <name>
```

Set up an AIX or LDAP group for your admins and then assign them to that group. Then run the above command to assign the admin authority to that group.

Some further information for you:
If you have 9.7 or higher, then you can separate out other authorities such as granting `DBADM WITH` or `WITHOUT DATAACCESS` and `WITH` or `WITHOUT ACCESSCTRL` (`WITH` is the default). There is also the SECADM authority.

To grant everything under 9.7 or higher to mimic what you would have received in lower versions of DB2 then

```
grant DBADM,SECADM,DATAACCESS,ACCESSCTRL on database to (user or group) <name>
```

If you are talking about instance authorities, then you can add them to the groups that are assigned to the `SYSADM`,`SYSCTRL`,`SYSMAINT`, or `SYSMON` DB2 groups. (Although it sounds like you don't want that. I am merely mentioning it for holistics.)

For a good overview of DB2 priveleges, I would recommend checking out the [Authorities Overview page](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0055206.html) in Information Center.